# JavaScript function performed on 6 id's at a time (return after 6 calls ?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I am wondering if there is a function I can use so that I can seperate data being called into groups of 6.

here is the long form of the code

```
var currentResults;

function init() {
    getProducts();
}

function getProducts() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"php/products.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { public: true },
        success:function(result){
            processResults(result);
        }
    });
 }

function processResults(results) {
     currentResults = null;

    if (!results && !results.products) 
        return; 

    currentResults = results.products;

    for (var i = 0; i < results.products.length; i++) {
        processResult(results.products[i]);
    }

     $(".galleryitem").click(handleThumbnailClick);
 }

function processResult(result) {
    var newDiv = '<div id="galleryitem' + result.id + '" class="galleryitem">';

    newDiv += '<div class="imageHover" style="background: ' + result.color + '">&nbsp;</div>';
    newDiv += '<img class="galleryImage" src="' + encodeImagePath(result.thumbnail) + '" />';

    if (result.artist)
        newDiv +=   '<div class="imageArtist">' + result.artist + '</div>';

    newDiv += '< /div>';

    $('#gallery').append(newDiv);

}
```

i would like the function to be able to sort the images to groups of 6, something like this... (see areas at bottom with ***'s)

```
 function processResult(result) {
    var newDiv = '<div id="galleryitem' + result.id + '" class="galleryitem">';

    newDiv += '<div class="imageHover" style="background: ' + result.color + '">&nbsp;</div>';
    newDiv += '<img class="galleryImage" src="' + encodeImagePath(result.thumbnail) + '" />';

    if ***(!!first 6 called!!)***
        newDiv +=   '<div class="imageArtist">' + result.artist + '</div>';

    newDiv += '< /div>';

    $('#galleryfirst').append(newDiv);

    if ***(!!second 6 called!!)***
        newDiv +=   '<div class="imageArtist">' + result.artist + '</div>';

    newDiv += '< /div>';

    $('#gallerysecond').append(newDiv);
}
```

Is doing something like this possible? Or does this whole code need an overhaul?

Comment: It's not very clear what' you're asking for. Do you want to group all products in groups of 6, or group the first 6 together, and then all remaining products are group together?

Comment: Are you trying to group products together by artist under a common heading?

Comment: I'm trying to group the products together by their release: top 6 from this year, bottom 6 from last year. thank you!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, pass the index:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < results.products.length; i++) {
    processResult(results.products[i], i);
 }
```

Then check it:

```
function processResult(result, index) {
   var newDiv = ...

   //check if the index is a multiple of 6
   if(index % 6 == 0){
      //do something every six results
   }
```

HTH,

-Ted

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to append the new items to different DIVs, the `processResults` function might be the better place to do this:

```
function processResults(results) {
    var i = 0,
        length = results.length,
        first = $("#galleryfirst"),
        second = $("gallerysecond");

    first.append('<div class="imageArtist">' + results[0].artist + '</div>');

    for (i; i < 6 && i < length; i++) {
        processResult(results[i], first);
    }

    if (length > 6) {
        second.append('<div class="imageArtist">' + results[6].artist + '</div>');

        for (i = 6; i < 12 && i < length; i++) {
            processResult(results[i], second);
        }
    }
}

function processResult(product, containerId) {
    var newDiv = "...";

    // build the HTML for newDiv...

    $(containerId).append(newDiv);
}
```

Comment: this seems close! but i can't figure out how to make it work correctly... as of now, the results are being completely lost... any other ideas?